# Debian: is there a shortcut for switching from Ubuntu to Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, conversion

I have been running Ubuntu 20 and I want to switch to Debian 10. I know how to back up my important software, install Debian 10 from a proper ISO image, and then restore my backed-up software onto the newly installed Debian system.

However, I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a shorter procedure for doing such an Ubuntu-to-Debian conversion, possibly via `apt` or some other utility. I have searched on line and not found anything like this, but perhaps I am overlooking something.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 is far ahead of Debian 10.  In theory you could change the [sources](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list), and then make some [pinning rules](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt_preferences) to allow downgrades, but downgrading is not supported or tested and will probably fail.  It's safest to install from scratch.

Comment: Actually on second thought, there are quite a few other differences between Ubuntu and Debian.  I don't think just changing the sources is enough.  You'd somehow need to replace some of the fundamental packages too.

Comment: Oh well ... I was just hoping, although I haven't been optimistic about finding such a shortcut.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If nothing else I think you would run into issues with configuration, especially because apt is designed to preserve config files.

Answer (score 2):

I use a separate partition for `/home`. I also have `/opt`, `/usr/local`, `/var/html`, and maybe some others are sym-linked (or bind-mounted) to `/home`. I can then replace the OS, but keep all my files.

This is not specific to the mentioned distos. I have used it to install newer versions of Debian over older ones (when the update went wrong. Yes Debian to Debian is not 100% reliable). Switch distros Redhat, Ubuntu, Debian.

I would get a list of installed packages, and back up `/etc` (there will be some config in there that you have forgotten about).

Another technique (however it needs you to have thought about it a long time ago) is to use configuration management to install the system: at least some scripts that will install all but the basics, and `augtool` (or just `cp` to a `*.d` directory ) for config, but preferably something like puppet.

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated 5/320 machines from Ubuntu 22.04 to Debian 12 with https://github.com/alexmyczko/autoexec.bat/blob/master/config.sys/ubuntu-deluxe

It is not yet fully automatic but I accept patches…

Comment: Um... I would try a few experiments with VM's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is "5/320"? It failed on 315 machines?

Comment: no I just did not get to run it on those yet…

Answer (score 0):

I think going to debian 11 would be easier. Also, everything depends on how basic your system is. If you don't have much more than a debootstrap, small upgrades should work.

I am currently in the process of converting a VM from Debian 11 to a stripped down ubuntu 22.04. I needed to convert it to 22.04 which meant some, but not many, upgrades. I needed to downgrade dpkg, because the zstd is not supported by dpkg provided by debian 11, but is by 20.04 (though the version number is lower). If moving from debian to ubuntu, you should install ubuntu-minimal afterwards. I do not know if debian has a similar package.

After conversion, from bullseye to jammy, I get this when logging on:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.0-14-amd64 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Linux bullseye 5.10.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29) x86_64

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

through ssh. Interestingly, it did not change the ecdsa key.